# Best way to check for format matching

Tags: c

Lets say I expect some input that will look like:

```
0x$$ : #####;
```

Where $$ will be some 2 digit number, and ##### will be some 5 digit number.

Just to make sure people are being careful with their entries, lets say I want to be very strict about formatting. So if you forget the '0x', its invalid. If you forget the ';', its invalid.

An easy way to do this would be just a bunch of if statements:

```
if((input[0]!= '0')|(input[1]!='x')|...){return -1;}
```

However this seems messy and cumbersome. Is there a better implementation that can acheive this same effect?

Comment: You could use a regular expression library to test each input line against a suitable regular expression.  Alternatively, since you have fixed-width fields, it should be pretty easy to check on a field-by-field basis instead of a character by character basis.  But as it stands, your question is too open-ended for a specific answer.

Comment: it would be easy with `regex`

Comment: The library function `scanf` may let you describe an exact pattern match but the syntax is pretty complex so it is hard to get it right. Sinse you input format is pretty short and simple, I would just iterate over the characters and check them one by one.